# Set location latitude/longitude getting values from edittext

Tags: android, location, double

I'm working on a location app. I want to create a proximity alert. For this I have 2 edittexts where I set latitude and longitude.

First of all, I retrieve the location coordenates automatically from my location using `getLastKnownLocation()`, and I save this values into the edittexts. But, I need to be able to set manually the location coordenates into the edittexts to set the proximity alert.

So, to create the proximity alert, I must get the coordinates from the edittext, and this sopposses some value conversion.

But what I don't know is how to do this conversion back. To comprend this much better, here is the code:

```
//Get location depending on the better service
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, true);
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

//Make conversion to show Location coordinates in edittexts
private static final NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.########");
latitudeEditText.setText(nf.format(mLocation.getLatitude()));
longitudeEditText.setText(nf.format(mLocation.getLongitude()));
```

Here is where I need help. Now I need to get values from  `latitudeEditText` and `longitudeEditText` and set them again into `mLocation`.

I assume this would be done in a way like: `mLocation.setLatitude("double value")` but my doubt is how to make the conversion back from the decimal value of the edittext to the double value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just finally solved this way.

To set the double value of the Location coordinates on a String or similar:

```
latitudeEditText.setText(mLocation.convert(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.FORMAT_DEGREES));
longitudeEditText.setText(mLocation.convert(mLocation.getLongitude(), mLocation.FORMAT_DEGREES));
```

To do the same back:

```
mLocation.setLatitude(mLocation.convert(latitudeEditText.getText().toString()));
mLocation.setLongitude(mLocation.convert(longitudeEditText.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `mLocation.setLatitute(Double.parseDouble(latitudeEditText.getText().toString()));`

similarly:
`mLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitudeEditText.getText().toString()));`

i hope it helps.

Comment: please keep in mind that u need to verify the `EditText`s values before doing this. i.e. the `EditText`s contain values which can be converted to doubles.

Comment: this should be done using some kind of exception? could you prive an example? I have still to learn a bit more about exceptions

Comment: Well, seems that this solution doesn't work. This is what i get on LogCat: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "43,249502"`